# E/OpenGLRenderer: Font size too large to fit in cache - when using AutoSizing TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-support-library

On tablet emulator, android does not display correctly textview when using [AutoSizing](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview) from [Support Library](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview).

1. Are there any way to fix without disabling hardware acceleration?
2. Why this wasn't fixed even using Support Library?

.

```
E/OpenGLRenderer: Font size too large to fit in cache. width, height = 347, 578
    Font size too large to fit in cache. width, height = 74, 610
    Font size too large to fit in cache. width, height = 347, 578
    Font size too large to fit in cache. width, height = 74, 610
```

---

> This is not duplicated question because its about AutoSizing TextView recently released and with focus in not using same common way to fix.